# How to check if record exists or not using Anko?

Tags: android, sqlite, anko

I am learning to fetching data from sqlite using anko. I can print the data successfully (if the record exist) but my application always crash when the data doesn't exist.

the error says:

> parseSingle accepts only cursors with a single entry

I know exactly the meaning of error, I just dont know how to solve it.

here is the code for query:

```
 fun getUserByUid(uid: Int): UserModel
 { 
    val data = context.database.use {
        val db = context.database.readableDatabase
        val columns = UserModel.COLUMN_ID + "," + UserModel.COLUMN_NAME + "," + UserModel.COLUMN_API_KEY

        val query = db.select(UserModel.TABLE_NAME, columns)
                .whereArgs("(uid = {userId})",
                        "userId" to uid)

        query.exec {
            val rowParser = classParser<UserModel>()
            parseSingle(rowParser) // this line that trigger error exception
        }
    }

    return data
}
```

I tried to find `count` function in `query` or `rowParser` variable to check if the record exist or not but could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the wiki page.
https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#parsing-query-results

Parsing query results

So we have some Cursor, and how can we parse it into regular classes? Anko provides functions parseSingle, parseOpt and parseList to do it much more easily.

Method  Description
parseSingle(rowParser): T   Parse exactly one row
parseOpt(rowParser): T? Parse zero or one row
parseList(rowParser): List   Parse zero or more rows
Note that parseSingle() and parseOpt() will throw an exception if the received Cursor contains more than one row.

Comment: oh i thought parseSingle also accept null record. okay i am gonna try it with parseList.